# ng-if dependent element not disappearing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've got the following problem:

When clicking a button my searchResults window opens due to 'displayResults' is set on 'true'. But when clicking on the close button it's not closed even if `$scope.displayResults` is set to `false` again.

html

```
<section id="searchResults" data-ng-if="displayResults">
    <h2>Suchergebnisse:</h2>
    <div id="closeMenuS">&#10060;</div>
    <ul data-ng-repeat="x in sItems">
       ....
    </ul>
</section>
```

AngularJS

```
         $http({
            method : "POST",
            url : "/searchFor",
            data: {item: sI, dID: searchID}
          }).then(function(response){

            if(response.data.length > 0 || response.data != 'undefined'){

                $("#sidebar").css({pointerEvents: "none"});
                $("#default").css({pointerEvents: "none"});

                $scope.displayResults = true;
                $scope.sItems = [];

                for(let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
                    $scope.sItems[i] = response.data[i];
                }

                window.setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#closeMenuS").click(function(){
                        $scope.displayResults = false;

                        $("#sidebar").css({pointerEvents: "auto"});
                        $("#default").css({pointerEvents: "auto"});
                    });
                }, 30);



            }

         }, function myError(response) {

                $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;

          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in a callback in a jQuery listener, you need to explicitly apply the change. Try this:

```
                window.setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#closeMenuS").click(function(){
                        $scope.displayResults = false;
                        $scope.$apply();
                        $("#sidebar").css({pointerEvents: "auto"});
                        $("#default").css({pointerEvents: "auto"});
                    });
                }, 30);
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly!

Can you explain, when I need to use `apply` exactly?

Comment: Yes - in any case where you're out of the context of AngularJS, usually it happens in this kind of case - when you're in a callback after a jQuery function, the changes done in that callback aren't detected by AngularJS change detection, and so you need to explicitly call $scope.$apply() to tell AngularJS - "okay, I made a change that needs to be registered and if needed update the view".
Hope that helps! don't forget to mark the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

AngularJs has its own implementation for timeouts. By using the native `setTimeout()` you are hiding what you are trying to do from angular.
The result is that AngularJs has no idea that your `$scope` changed.

The correct way would be to inject the `$timeout` service and replace your `setTimeout()` call with `$timeout` (I stripped down the rest of the code for simplification):

```
angular.module("YourModule")
       .controller("YourController", ["$scope", "$timeout", YourController]);

function YourController($scope, $timeout)
{
    ...

    $scope.doSomeMagic = function()
    {
        $timeout(function()
        {
            $("#closeMenuS").click(function()
            {
                $scope.displayResults = false;

                $("#sidebar").css({pointerEvents: "auto"});
                $("#default").css({pointerEvents: "auto"});
            });
        }, 30);
    }

    ...
}
```

This is why the `$apply()` function suggested by Itamar works. You're basically forcing AngularJs to detect changes.
However, the better practice is to use the tools provided by AngularJs and avoid native javascript when possible.

Comment: Thanks, that explained it pretty well. =)